# Is it possible to allow the general public to upload a video to a specific YouTube account?

Tags: php, youtube

I am looking for a PHP based solution where users of my websites upload a video that will end up on my Youtube channel (not their own, for which there are plenty of well documented examples). Does anyone have tips on how to achieve this? I've heard of one case where CURL was involved but can't find a good example.

Comment: A good place to start would be the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert), they provide tons of documentation and code samples for PHP. If you have any troubles with code, feel free to come back.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your reply. I will have a look at that code :)